# SQL DB failing to send server email - intermittent

Tags: email-server, database, sql, troubleshooting, sql-server-2014

Recently, we noticed an issue in SASS 2014 logs regarding the failure of some emails to send:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2023-06-29T11:20:17). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
> )

In this case, 4 almost identical emails would be sent and one of them would occasionally fail. It appears to be completely random.

MaxFileSize is not an issue.

SQL Scheduler is not running around the time of the failure.

Last 6 Years - 140k emails sent with 5k of such failures.

Comment: The SMTP server it is configured to use is intermittently unresponsive or has some type of failure.